# Имитация нажатии клавиши

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, visual-c++, qt5

Имитацию нажатии клавиши делаю так:

```
keybd_event('C', 0,0,0);
keybd_event('C', 0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
```

Как сделать что бы имитация нажатии клавиши было только в определенном окне

Comment: keybd_event и так осуществляет отправку события клавиши в определенное окно (текущее активное окно в системе)

Comment: мне нужно что бы была отправка события не в активное окно, а в определенное, будь оно активное или пасивное

Comment: Поддерживаемого способа сделать это нет. Можно попробовать посылать через SendMessage сообщения WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP, но не факт, что результат будет соответствовать ожиданиям

Comment: События клавиатуры передаются активному окну, туда куда установлено фокус. Попробутйе активировать окно `SetActiveWindow` и установить фокус на нужном елементе `SetFocus`. В некоторых случаях будет работать SendMessage/PostMessage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет Windows ОС под рукой, чтобы проверить, но все же, попробуйте.

```
HWND wndHndl = FindWindow(_T("ApplicationName"), NULL);
PostMessage(wndHndl, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_A, 0);
```

Comment: все работает, спасибо

Comment: @SЌĬPクラス, рад помочь!

Comment: а с кликом мыши как то можно сделать? стоит создавать новую тему?

Comment: @SKIP, посмотрите, пожалуйста, вот этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5790851/6266408