# Нажатие клавиш в браузере

Tags: c#, c++, браузер

У меня есть сайт, там я должен проходить регистрацию, я хочу автоматизировать этот процесс...Вся суть в том, что я нажимаю `Tab` определенное количество раз ввожу почту и  пароль, затем еще раз `Tab` и кликаю по кнопки "Регистрация"

Вся проблема в том, что все эти действия проходят в браузере(Google Chrome или др.)
Я не знаю как это реализовать, а именно нажатие клавиш не в консоли, может быть нужно создать не консольное приложение?(Любой язык, но я пишу на C++ и C#)

Перекопал кучу интернета...

Comment: Попробуйте это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855895/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8

Comment: В браузере вы можете нажимать клавиши в одном единственном случае - если у вас плагин для браузера (нужно долго нудно копать SDK). Все остальные случаи - эмуляция нажатия клавиши. Для винды это keybd_event либо PostMessage

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Имитация нажатии клавиши](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855895/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b8)

Comment: Может стоит использовать get/post запросы а не эмуляцию клавиш?) Ну или на крайний случай использовать встроенный браузер?)

Comment: Для автоматических запросов есть программы-роботы... Не могу их перечислить. Ещё можно взять тот же COM InternetExplorer.Application, и через него управлять браузером. Там можно и кликать - и всё что угодно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаешь Cef инстанс и делаешь все что тебе нужно. Можно создать сразу CEF без показывания на экран, кстате.

Код на c#, но, думаю, ты сможешь без проблем его подстроить на плюсы, если с ними тебе удобнее:

1. сначала берешь координаты кнопки куда нужно кликнуть при помощи JS
2. Симулируешь клик при помощи CEF:

   ```
   public void MouseClick(int x, int y)
   {
       Browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 1, CefEventFlags.None);
       Thread.Sleep(15);
       Browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, true, 1, CefEventFlags.None);
   }
   ```

Для чего такие сложности спросишь ты? И почему бы не воспользоватся кликом при помощи JS?

Да потому, что в целях защиты от нехороших людей в браузерах целый ряд кликов блокируются. А вот этот клик сработает в любом случае.

Здесь можно найти пример аплоада файла без открытия openfiledialog:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690123/cef-upload-file-without-shown-openfiledialog

в общем... думаю ты идею уловил)

Еще есть вариант с Selenium. Но он будет работать медленнее. Зато стоково есть много удобных хреней вроде кучи селекторов/кликов/захвата текста, выбора елемента дропдауна по названию и подобных штук.

---

Еще может быть полезным почитать мои ответы здесь:
[Как пропарсить сайт с авторизацией?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/878886/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9/915156#915156)

была еще какая-то линка где я развернуто описывал самые разные способа для взаимодействия и парсинга сайтов, но мне ее не удалось найти =(((((

Comment: А почту не блокирует? Если, скажем за 24 часа отправит 20000 или более писем ?

Comment: думаю, это зависит от почты. Но вообще для отправки почты я советую использовать програмный код работающий с почтой напрямую -- без прослойки в виде браузера.

Comment: С программным кодом был момент когда письма попадали в спам. Думаю нужно проверит это

Comment: Подозреваю что в современных имейл системах есть проверка "на похожесть" имейла высылаемого. То есть проверяется уникальность и если текст очень похож на несколько сотен других и имеет количество символов выше некоего уровня -- то автоматически попадает в спам(если у получателя он не в "белом списке" в контактах). Точнее лично я бы сделал такую систему в том числе и не думаю что я единственный кто к этому додумался) PS: а вообще спам рассылкой заниматся не хорошо. Закругляйся с этим.